# Алгоритм нахождения количества путей длины k в неориентированном графе

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм нахождения количества путей длины k в неориентированном графе

Comment: первая ссылка https://e-maxx.ru/algo/fixed_length_paths, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272119/finding-the-number-of-paths-of-given-length-in-a-undirected-unweighted-graph

Comment: Видел эти алгоритмы.
Но разве они не для ориентированных графов? Для неориентированных количество путей будет увеличиваться с увеличением k. Не сильно разбираюсь в этом вопросе, поэтому не могли бы развеять мои сомнения?

Comment: в последней ссылке говорится именно об неориентированном графе